# Button size on iPad

Tags: ipad, accessibility

In the iPad settings I can change the text size to a bigger font. This doesn't change the font size of the back buttons and the search field. How can I change those?

Comment: Is this for a specific app or all apps in general?

Comment: This is for the apps in general. Like when I open the Settings > "background", then there is a back button (or link) on top. Then if I choose a background image, there is a bottom bar with several links (cancel, etc). I would like to have to buttons or links larger.

Comment: You didn't mention it specifically, but did you go into Accessibility and change the text there?

Comment: Yes I did. Those settings change the font size inside apps. I see the change immediately reflected in the settings app. But not in the system buttons like top and bottom bars and buttons, and the search bar.

Comment: I don't think those can be changed.  At least, I've never seen nor heard of any other way of changing those font sizes (outside of Accessibility, I mean).